# Github actions review dog fails when running aslant with review dig

Tags: typescript, react-native, github, github-actions, gitlab-ci.yml

I am currently having issues running my review dog in GitHub actions. I have been following this tutorial: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-eslint-with-reviewdog and this is what I am trying to install: https://github.com/reviewdog/reviewdog. This is my first time trying to use GitHub actions.

What I am trying to do is to get the review dog to run once a or is created. this is my .yml file:

```
name: Review Dog
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  eslint:
    name: Sniffing code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - run: npm install
      - uses: reviewdog/action-eslint@v1
        with:
          reporter: github-pr-review
```

And this is the error that I receive:

[image]

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.1.6",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the action tries to annotate the PR and for that it needs Write access to your repo. That used to be the default until last week, when the new default was turned to read-only.

Add the ‘permissions’ keyword to your workflow with the pull request scope set to write. So like this:

permissions:
pull-requests: write

More info here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs